# Calcular a soma de elementos repetidos em Angular-JS usando ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

No código abaixo é exibido uma lista de despesas usando ng-repeat.
Para cada elemento é mostrado a descrição e o valor.
Qual a maneira mais simples de mostrar esse total?

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <th>DESCRIÇÃO</th>
    <th>VALOR</th>
    <th class="text-center">Ação</th>
    <tr ng-repeat="despesa in despesas | filter: filtro">
        <td>
            <a ng-href="#/despesa/{{despesa._id}}">{{despesa.nome}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>R${{despesa.valor}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <button ng-click="remove(despesa)" class="btn btn-warning">
                Remover
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    Total: {{total}}
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe algumas maneiras práticas de sumarizar no [angular](/questions/tagged/angular), **exemplo**:

***1): Calculando dentro do `ng-repeat`***

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.despesas = [
        {'nome': '1', valor:100},
        {'nome': '2', valor:20},
        {'nome': '3', valor:40},
    ];
    $scope.remove = function(){
    };
    $scope.total = 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<table class="table table-hover">
    <th>DESCRIÇÃO</th>
    <th>VALOR</th>
    <th class="text-center">Ação</th>
    <tr ng-repeat="despesa in despesas">
        <td>
            <a ng-href="#/despesa/{{despesa._id}}">{{despesa.nome}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>R${{despesa.valor}}</td>
        <td class="text-center" ng-init="$parent.total = $parent.total + despesa.valor">
            <button ng-click="remove(despesa)" class="btn btn-warning">
                Remover
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    Total: {{total}}
</table>
</div>
```

<sub>***Observação:*** se tiver algum filtro não seria a mais recomendável, se a regra for a soma geral, porque, a soma será aplicado também o filtro.</sub>

***2) Calculando com uma `function`:***

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.despesas = [
        {'nome': '1', valor:100},
        {'nome': '2', valor:20},
        {'nome': '3', valor:40},
    ];
    $scope.remove = function(){
    };
    $scope.getTotal = function()
    {
      var s = 0;
      for(i = 0; i < $scope.despesas.length; i++)
      {
        s = s + $scope.despesas[i].valor;
      }        
      return s;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<table class="table table-hover">
    <th>DESCRIÇÃO</th>
    <th>VALOR</th>
    <th class="text-center">Ação</th>
    <tr ng-repeat="despesa in despesas">
        <td>
            <a ng-href="#/despesa/{{despesa._id}}">{{despesa.nome}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>R${{despesa.valor}}</td>
        <td class="text-center" ng-init="$parent.total = $parent.total + despesa.valor">
            <button ng-click="remove(despesa)" class="btn btn-warning">
                Remover
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    Total: {{getTotal()}}
</table>
</div>
```

<sup>**Uma das duas formas pode encaixar na sua duvida, mas, eu acredito que a segunda seja a melhor, talvez, mediante a sumarização total dos itens contidos nesse `array`, mas, é legal ter várias formas possíveis de solucionar um problema e a melhor que se encaixa conforme a sua regra de negócio.**</sup>